# How to Store DateTime in IsolatedStorage

Tags: datetime, windows-phone-8

What I'm trying to implement is a timing feature, whereby after a certain amount of days a user is notified of an activity or event occurring. For instance, today is Monday and three days later I want to give a notification to the user. How can I store this information in my app and reuse it?

Comment: Does the app have to be running to give the notification or should it automatically give it?

Comment: I would prefer it to be running, the notification wouldn't occur unless the app was launched and then the DateTime was checked.

Comment: can you please let me know if the answer is helpful or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. Create a class to hold your event details.

```
public class Event
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

then populate a list with your events, To set the date you can add days from Today to get the date ahead like this.

```
Event evt = new Event()
{
    ID = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(),
    Title = "Your Event",
    Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(3),
    Finished = false
};
```

and add that to the list. Then you can serialize the list to a JSON string and create a JSON file in the IsolatedStorage. Then when your application Navigates to the MainPage or when a particular event fires you can retrieve that list and compare the date like this.

```
if (evt.Date.ToShortDateString() == DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString())
{
    // Do something..
}
```